# Creating individual offline layers for ArcGIS Runtime (100.x) map

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm wanting to convert a fairly large ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.7 WPF project to 100.x   The project uses entirely offline content, which is stored in Runtime Geodatabases that are created in ArcMap (File ==> Share As ==> ArcGIS Runtime Content)  I programmatically build the map using the layers in multiple runtime geodatabases.  The map is entirely read-only, there is no data editing need.

At this website https://developers.arcgis.com/net/offline-maps-scenes-and-data/  about halfway down on the page, it says the following:

**An alternative to taking a map offline is to construct the map using individual offline layers. Layers can either reference offline data sources on the device or be exported from suitable online services. Working directly with layers gives you full flexibility to compose your own offline map.**

This is exactly what I want to do (using data stored on the device), but of course, it doesn't give any recommendation or code samples on how to do it.  Basically what I'm looking for is what the best way is to package the feature layers that I want to use in a way that's best for a custom (programmatically) made offline map.

What I've tried so far...In ArcGIS Pro 2.7

1. Package the data in a mobile map package.  I've sort of gotten this to work, but you have to "remove the layers" from the mobile map first before you can use them in your own map. Not sure if mobile map package is the ideal solution because I don't want to use the map in the mobile map package (I just want to use the feature (data) layers)
2. Create a mobile geodatabase (under Data Management Tools ==> Create Mobile Geodatabase) and then add my feature layers to that (using the "Feature Class to Geodatabase" tool)  However, when I open the mobile geodatabase in a WPF app, the Geodatabase.GeodatabaseFeatureTables list is empty (it's like it doesn't recognize that my feature layer as a GeodatabaseFeatureTable)

I need to be able to export/package my feature layers using the "ArcGIS Pro version of ArcPy" (preferably this instead of using the old Python 2.7 version...)  So this eliminates the "Create Runtime Content" method used in ArcMap.

Thoughts/ideas/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your old ArcMap process could be consumed using the [Geodatabase](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/api-reference/) class. However, it seems you're upgrading the data creation process too and won't be using ArcMap any more.

While Pro recently added the ability to create mobile geodatabases, they're not consumable by Runtime yet. We anticipate adding that capability soon, but it's not quite there yet.

Right now, the Mobile Map Package approach is probably your best bet for what you want to achieve. The map in the mobile map package is very lightweight. I'd just open the map, [Clone](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/api-reference/) each layer and add the cloned layer to your map. You should then be able to discard the map you got from the mobile map package. In other words, the mobile map package becomes a delivery container for your data, and the map in the mobile map package is just an access tool.

I assume your data is not sourced from feature services. If it is, another possibility could be to use the Python API to download mobile geodatabases from the feature services and sideload them to your app. That requires that the service has sync enabled though, so if you don't own the service you might not be able to do that.

You might find the [Offline guide topic](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-location-services/offline/) helpful, as well as the [WPF sample app](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/). Unfortunately we don't have a sample that does the exact thing you're trying to do (mobile map packages are typically used to deliver maps and the data behind them, not just data) but you might find some helpful samples.